# If a customer purchased certain products in period 1, what did they buy in period 2?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to create a query to see what products a customer purchased in period 2 if they purchased product 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 in period 1.

I'm working on a `DimProduct` table using the columns

```
CustomerID, PeriodID, ProductID
```

I've tried some messy `IF` and `WHERE` statements and haven't been able to figure it out. Any tips would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: A dimension does not normally have purchase dates. A fact does. Are you able to write a query that just does the first bit (finds customers that purchased certain products in period 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.ProductID
FROM DimProduct p2
WHERE p2.PeriodID = 2 and 
    EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM DimProduct as p1
            WHERE p1.PeriodID = 1 and p1.ProductID in (1,2,3,4,5)
                and p1.CustomerID = p2.CustomerID);
```

(if script is not working fix it. it is just an idea)

Comment: Got it to run! Thanks for taking the time to help. Happy Holidays, Mr. Murygin!

Answer (score 0):

You can join the DimProduct to itself, on the CustomerID, and add your filter conditions to the WHERE clause. Something like this would get you what you're looking for.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p2.ProductID
FROM DimProduct p2
INNER JOIN DimProduct p1 ON p1.CustomerID = p2.CustomerID
WHERE p2.PeriodID = 2 
AND p1.PeriodID = 1
AND p1.ProductID in (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Comment: This worked fantastically. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Happy Holidays!